# Why is 'rowmodctr' value in sys.sysindexes is different for each index on same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was doing some research on index usage in one of the heavily used tables in our environment. I have used following command to get the number of rows changed/modified in the table since the last server restart. But i have noticed the values is different for each index on the same table.

```
select rowmodctr from sys.sysindexes where id=25
```

SQL Server Version: 2008 SP4 x64

Please someone clarify why this values i different by index in the same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`rowmodctr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysindexes-transact-sql) shows you the number of rows update/inserted/delete since the last time the Statistics were updated for the table.

Your assumption of it giving you rows changed since the last server restart is wrong.

After statistics are updated depending on what indexes were affected by the updates/deletes/inserts the column in question can show different numbers for different indexes.